# What is the AHK keycode for the auto-rotate button?

Tags: windows, autohotkey, keycode

I'm attempting to remap a physical button on my laptop that triggers the auto-rotate toggle inside Windows 10.  I know the keyboard shortcut for this Windows+O which would be #o in AutoHotKey.

With the following code snippet I can swap the autorotate key and volume down key (just an example).

```
#o::Volume_Down
Volume_Down::#o
```

But what is the underlying signal/keycode that Windows+O triggers, and can I trigger it with a keycode instead of with #o?

Comment: Read https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys
and try to find out the scan code of this key via Key history.

Comment: I have Windows 10 and Win+O doesn't do anything for me. well, I don't even ...................

Comment: @Blauhirn that keyboard shortcut only works if your screen is rotatable.  I'm not sure how Windows knows.

Comment: @user3419297 I get LWin (down), o (down), o (up), LWin (up) when pressing the special key on the side of the laptop.  Looks like it is just invoking the windows shortcut. LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is no keycode for this.  It's a key combination: Win+O.  The key on the side of the laptop simply sends Win+O.